# Talend error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \” \' \\ )" syntax error

Tags: java, regex, talend

I am trying to bypass space and "-" in the regular expression in talend.

I want to replace all the characters with "_" other than numbers, letters, space and -. Below is the regular expression I wrote. It's giving me a syntax error.

```
row1.pl_name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,\s\-\"]","_").replace("\"", "").replaceAll("(,)*$", "").replace("__", "_")
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,\\s\"-]","_")` - just double escape the `\s` and put the `-` at the end of the character class. I also think `.replace("\"", "")` is redundant as you already replace `"` with `_` before.

Comment: I tried the \\s, same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape more of your backslashes in the string literal:

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9,\\s\\-\"]"
              ^  ^  Add these backslashes
```

Read the compiler message: `\s` and `\-` are invalid escape sequences.